# How to resolve this filter Processbuilder error?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, terminal, command, processbuilder

not able run this coomand

```
    List<String> command= new ArrayList<>();
    command.add("ffmpeg");
    command.add("-i");
    command.add(file1Path);
    command.add("-i");
    command.add(file2Path);
    command.add("-filter_complex");
    command.add("\"[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]\"");
    command.add("-map");
    command.add("\"[aout]\"");
    command.add(outputFilePath);
```

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = processBuilder.start();

error   Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f9dd8d05cc0] Trailing garbage after a filter: apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]"
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f9dd8d05cc0] Error parsing filterchain '"[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]"' around: apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]"

How to resolve

I want to run this command which is basically merging two mono audio file to stereo

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: @user16320675 yes they are needed

Comment: @user16320675 ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp3

Comment: @user16320675 this is the command and left.mp3 and right.mp3 are the audio files

Comment: @user16320675 https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html this the documentation and i tried after removing the quotes also, that is not a working command prompt

Comment: @user16320675 can you tell me the correct way to write this

Comment: @user16320675     /*
       Mix multiple single channel audio files to give a single file, in MULTIPLE CHANNEL (STEREO),
       files can be of different length but starting point will be same, the duration of output will be the duration of longest input file.
       file1  : 1111111111111111111111111
       file2  : 2222222222222
       Output : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX where X = [1,2] combination of audios
       Command : ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp3
   */ this the task i want to do

Comment: @user16320675 can you please send your code